# How to select entire html except for one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to disable scrolling except for one div, which is a modal pop up. On phones it extends past the bottom of the screen so I need only that div which we will call `#div100` for this.

I'm sure once I have this, I can just unbind to re-enable scrolling once the modal closes.

**How can I disable scrolling except for one div?**

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="div1">...</div>
            <div id="div100">...</div>
            <div id="div3">...</div>
        </div>
        <div id="upper-div">...</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
$('.button').bind("click touchend", function(){
         $('div').not('#div100').bind('touchmove', false);
});
```

I was thinking it would be easier by calling on `div` rather than `body` or `html`, but I don't mind if it is easier to do it with `body` or `html`

Comment: there is no `.button` element

Comment: the .button is in one of the divs. It's in div1. I didn't list it because I didn't think it mattered for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a slightly different approach:  Select every element of the HTML `querySelectorAll("*")` should do it, then loop through and bind "touchmove" "false" on each of those. Then, select #div100, and unbind it there.

You may have to adjust precisely WHAT ELEMENT you apply that "querySelectorAll," as binding something to #div100's ancestors may propagate down to #div100.  So, `document.querySelectorAll` may not be the best place, but rather the parentNode of #div100, so only #div100's siblings get that bound.  Of course, using jquery, you can select the elements with whatever methods you want.  I just reference querySelectorAll as it's something I use often in vanilla.

EDIT:

Try something like this:

```
    $("container").each(function(){
        $(this).bind('touchmove', false);
    }
    $("#div100").bind('touchmove', true);
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
    $("container").each(function(){
        if ($(this)!=$("#div100")){
            $(this).bind('touchmove', false);
        }
    }
```

Either way should work.  Pardon my syntax, I'm not terribly familiar with jquery.

Comment: Can you give me an example, I have never used that before, and don't really know how to implement that. It would be a great help!

Comment: There, is that better?

Comment: Yes! Thanks, I started reading up on it. I'm working on it right now. I'll comment back

Comment: Be careful with my use of 'this' there - I'm fixing it now, but since it's a jquery context, the 'this' should actually be '$(this)'.

Comment: Ahhh still can't get it! I'll keep tweaking it and hopefully I'll get this. Thanks for your help

Comment: What exactly is happening?  Which method are you attempting to use?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.button').bind("click touchend", function(){
     if($('div').attr("id") == '#div100')
        $('div').bind('touchmove', false);
     else
        $('div').bind('touchmove', true);

});
```

Try this.